# Match Snowflake MD5 to Python MD5

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, md5

I'm trying to match the MD5 output from Snowflake `md5_number_lower64` to the MD5 output in Python for the same string.

What's the code to pull this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick example (from a teammate) to pull this off. In Python:

```py
import hashlib
def md5_number_lower64(msg):
    return int.from_bytes(hashlib.md5(msg.encode('utf-8')).digest()[8:], 'big')
```

returns:

```
$ print(md5_number_lower64('Snowflake'))
> 9203306159527282910`
```

which matches Snowflake's result:

```sql
select md5_number_lower64('Snowflake');
-- 9203306159527282910
```

Docs:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/md5_number_lower64.html

> Returns a 64 bit unsigned integer that represents the lower 64 bits of the message digest. This representation is useful for maximally efficient storage and comparison of MD5 digests.

Comment: I wrote a Medium article about this (https://medium.com/snowflake/validating-a-python-hash-function-inside-snowflake-3c9255bf6bc4) and have another coming about doing the same with Java.

Comment: That's a great blog post, thanks Dylan!